# Alternative tool to Photoshop that allows editing PSD files with "smart objects"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, smartobject

Are there any other tools than Adobe Photoshop available that allow to edit PSD files that contain *smart objects*?
(I checked GIMP but it doesn't support smart objects)

Comment: Hello and wellcome to GD.SE. To answer your question. Similar features yes but do it for PSD files havent heard of any.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment I don't believe there are any, but Affinity has it on their list of features to implement. They're both (Affinity Designer [AI Replacement] and Affinity Photo [PS Replacement]) under development and the creators have been doing an excellent job adding new features and fixing bugs regularly.

This is the most recent thread on Smart Objects I'm aware of: [Photoshop Linked Smart Objects on Affinity](https://affinity.serif.com/forum/index.php?/topic/6840-photoshop-linked-smart-objects/)

I've tried the software but not with Smart Objects to say how well it currently works or not.

Answer (score 1):

I found a online editor which supports PS smart objects as a free alternative to Affinity: https://www.photopea.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75310)

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought it could help as I was looking for an alternative the whole day and finally found this. I am not affiliated in any way with this site.

Comment: Holy macaroni! I had pretty low expectations as I clicked that link, but the support for PS smart objects is phenomenal! Better than Affinity Photo 2 and Adobe's own Photoshop Elements. (This should certainly be the accepted answer, although it looks like the OP has long since departed.)